# I am trying to prevent my delete icon from getting the strike-through function when applied to 'LI' elements

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I've tried to get the strike-through just in the "LI" elements, but what happened was the "TRASH" icon is taking this strike-through as well as shown in the screenshot below,

[image: the screenshot below to show you exactly what I am getting out of that]

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#todo');
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let button = document.querySelector('#Clear-all')
let list = document.querySelector('#list');
let el = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
const deleteButton = document.getElementsByTagName("i");

// let's add the elements
function Items() {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let text = input.value;
    if (text === "") {
      alert('You must add something in the field below');
    } else {
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      li.innerHTML = text;
      list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
      input.value = "";
      var createDeleteButton = document.createElement("i");
      createDeleteButton.classList.add("fa", "fa-trash");
      li.appendChild(createDeleteButton);
      createDeleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        li.innerHTML = "";
      })
    }
  })
}

Items();

// to add a strike through done 
list.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('done');
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="add-element">
  <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Type anything">
  <button id="btn">Add</button>
  <button id="Clear-all">Clear List</button>
</div>
<div class="element-list">
  <div id="div">
    <ul id="list">
      <li id="items"></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you mind adding a screenshot of the DOM?
From my xp, you are adding the `.done` class in the `li` and by doing so, your button which uses font awesome I suspect, by being a font, it gets strikethrough.

So, CSS tweaks would do.

`li.done: { text-decoration: line-through; };` instead of `.done: { text-decoration: line-through; };`

Comment: I just did but still getting the strike-through on the LI and the Icon

Comment: Try forcing the `button` style to use no text-decoration: `button { text-decoration: none; }`

Comment: You meant the "Icon"? if that's what you meant it didn't work as well, It's actually not taking the {text-decoration: none;} I tried to change the color of the icon and it works but it won't take the text decoration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'r looking for is [Event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```
createDeleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault(); // <= Not sure if you need this one, just for precaution 
    event.stopPropagation();
    li.remove();
})
```

Edit :

`list.addEventListener('click', ...` is on the `ul` element so it will affect all the elements inside the ul, all the `li` including the delete button `i`, where ever you click inside the `ul` the event will be triggered, I made some change to your code, removed the `ul` event, add a checkbox for each element with an event listener, in order for your `li` elements to be stroke through individually.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('#todo');
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let clear = document.querySelector('#Clear-all')
let list = document.querySelector('#list');
let el = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

// let's add the elements
function Items() {
  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    let text = input.value;
    if (text === "") {
      alert('You must add something in the field below');
    } else {
      // Create Item
      let li = document.createElement("li");
      list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
      input.value = "";
      
      // Create a text container element
      const textContainer = document.createElement('b');
      textContainer.innerText = text;
      li.appendChild(textContainer);
      
      // Add a delete button
      const deleteButton = document.createElement("i");
      deleteButton.classList.add("fa", "fa-trash");
      deleteButton.innerText = "X"; // <= Remove this line if you want to remove the X
      li.appendChild(deleteButton);
      deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        li.remove();
      });
      
      //Add a checkbox for the strike through
      const checkbox = document.createElement("input");
      checkbox.type = "checkbox";
      deleteButton.classList.add("fa", "fa-trash");
      li.prepend(checkbox);
      checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
        if(checkbox.checked) li.classList.add("done");
        else li.classList.remove("done");
      });
    }
  })
}

Items();

// Cear all function
clear.onclick = () => {
  list.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
.done  b{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

i {
  color: red;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-element">
  <input type="text" id="todo" placeholder="Type anything">
  <button id="btn">Add</button>
  <button id="Clear-all">Clear List</button>
</div>
<div class="element-list">
  <div id="div">
    <ul id="list">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry didn't get your problem in the first place ... edited my answer ... this is what you where trying to achieve ?

Comment: Well !! thank you so much for the help but I think it still doing the same thing even by replacing the "TRASH" icon with "X", the "X" now is getting the Strike-through also. I don't know why I feel like it doesn't have a solution :(

Comment: Reedited my answer ... add a `textContainer ` as a `b` element, and edited the css, now  the Strike-through will go only over the text inside the `b` element ... you can change the `b` to `span` if you don't want to handle the text bold effect

Comment: You are the best !! thank you it works perfectly!! but will it be a problem if I tried to have my TRASH icon back ?? instead of the X ??

Comment: I put the "X" here just for the illustration, you can remove it without a problem.